# 2 Comboboxes and 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, combobox

I've been working on a VB project where I use a **1st** drop down list to select a movie category and then in the **2nd** drop menu, movies from that category will be displayed. The movies are stored in a 2-dimensional array by category.

With help from folks here, I've been able to edit my array but I'm having problems with my .AddRange() function. What would I have to put in those parentheses for the list (for each category) to appear in my **2nd** combobox when the category is selected?

I tried:

- .AddRange (movie_list_combobox)
- .AddRange (movie_category_combobox)
- .AddRange (Array(movie_list_combobox))
- .AddRange (Array(movie_category_combobox))

Nothing has worked.

items changed:

1. Updated array
2. Instead of using if/else statement, I'm using for/next (no longer using Select Case either)
3. added addRange()

I've attached my code below:

```
Public Class Video_Form

Private Sub count_textbox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles count_textbox.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Count_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Count.Click

  count_textbox.Text = Me.movie_list_combobox.Items.Count

End Sub

Private Sub movie_categories_combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles movie_categories_combobox.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub movie_list_combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles movie_list_combobox.SelectedIndexChanged

  Dim Movies(,) As String = {{"Meet", "Oxford", "Sterilite"}, {"Sunflower", "Seeds", ""}, {"Black Box", "", ""}, {"Dancing ", "", ""}, {"Dictionary", "", ""}, {"Glue", "Flight", ""}}

  Dim row As Integer
  Dim column As Integer

  For movie_categories_combobox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    row = 0 To 2
    column = 0 To 0
    movie_list_combobox.Items.Clear()
    movie_list_combobox.Items.AddRange()
  Next

  For movie_categories_combobox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    row = 0 To 1
    column = 1 To 1
    movie_list_combobox.Items.Clear()
    movie_list_combobox.Items.AddRange()
  Next

  For movie_categories_combobox.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
    row = 0 To 0
    column = 2 To 2
    movie_list_combobox.Items.Clear()
    movie_list_combobox.Items.AddRange()
  Next

  For movie_categories_combobox.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
    row = 0 To 0
    column = 3 To 3
    movie_list_combobox.Items.Clear()
    movie_list_combobox.Items.AddRange()
  Next

  For movie_categories_combobox.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
    row = 0 To 0
    column = 4 To 4
    movie_list_combobox.Items.Clear()
    movie_list_combobox.Items.AddRange()
  Next

  For movie_categories_combobox.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
    row = 0 To 1
    column = 5 To 5
    movie_list_combobox.Items.Clear()
    movie_list_combobox.Items.AddRange()
  Next

  '//End If
  '//End Select

End Sub
```

Please let me know what part(s) of my code are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion your problem isn't very clear...btw maybe i can help you by telling you what would i do if i were in you. 
I'll declare a 2 dimension array in this way....for ex. funny films at index 0 and kolossal at index 1....

```
 Dim array as new string(1,2) ={{"Scary movie", "Ace ventura", "American pie"},   {"Titanic", "avatar", "quo vadis"}}
```

Then, populate the movie category combobox:

```
 movie_category_combobox.items.addRange(new string(){"Funny movies", "Kolossal"})
```

Finally, when the movie_category_combobox.SelectedIndexChanged has thrown, you only need to:

```
 'clear the movie combobox
 movie_list_combobox.items.clear() 

 'fill the movie combobox with the index at the selected position 
 movie_list.combobox.items.addrange(array(movie_category_combobox.selectedIndex) )
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: It was easier for me to view "the array" in excel and attempt to replicate the array using VB. The only part of my project that works right now is the count_click code. The main problem I have is with the if else statements. I want to know how to display the items in the array in the 2nd combo box. For example, in the Comedy category the movies that should display are "Meet, Oxford, Sterilite". If it is still confusing I guess I'll either try your method or edit my explanation to make it clearer.

Comment: Is the array in the code section "movie_list_combobox_SelectedIndexChanged" (close to the end of the code snippet) a proper two-dimensional array?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but i was working! ;) btw the 2nd point i've posted yesterday, populates the movie category combobox, so it does the job you need. "movie_category_combobox.SelectedIndexChanged" event handler doesn't need and "if...else if...else if.." block because items in the movie_category_combobox has the same order of the array variable (for ex.  movie_category_combobox.item(0) = "Funny movies" and at the same position, array(0) contains array of the funny films,  and so on for the other position...).

Comment: It's hard to explain but it is simple to understand! if you need further help i can post you a project (VB.NET or C#.NET as you like) to do this job...let me know! ;)

Comment: here you can find my example...it's done in vb.net in a simple and a little bit verbose way, but it explains all you need to complete your job. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60231308/SampleComboBox.rar